# How to update Qty on product save action?

Tags: magento-1.9, event-observer, stock, inventory, cataloginventory

I'm trying to update the StockData in `catalog_product_save_before` observer and not having any luck.

I can get the stock data like this

```
$_newProduct = $observer->getProduct();
$_newStock = $_newProduct->getStockData();
$PostQty = $_newStock['qty'];
```

I can update anything that isn't stock data like this

```
$_newProduct->setData('ebay_qty', $eBayQty);
```

I need to update the Qty based on other attributes. I have tried all these with no luck

```
$_newStock['qty'] = $NewQty; // Doesn't work
$_newStock->setData('qty', $NewQty); // Doesn't work
$_newStock->setQty($NewQty); // Doesn't work
```

I have also tried this

```
$_newStock = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($_newProduct);
$_newStock->setQty($PossibleQty);
$_newStock->save();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it not must be `catalog_product_save_before`, try `catalog_product_save_after instead` and this:

```
public function setQty(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    $stockQty = 999;
    $product = $observer->getProduct();
    $product->getStockItem()
        ->setData('qty', $stockQty)
        ->save();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for trying, but I already tried that. If you call $product->save() from catalog_product_save_after, it creates an endless loop saving the product.

Comment: Read carefully ... I call 'save()' on the stock item. Code is tested.

Comment: You are partially correct. I did call

Comment: You're completely correct. Thank you! I dismissed this because I was trying with save_after for many weeks and thought I had tried every possibility. But I think I was getting the stockItem incorrectly before. Thanks again! Not much info out there on this type of stuff.